# View stack or Drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, addsubview

I'm working on a calendar app and i have a lot of view-s in in each page of the scrollview. The problem is that on simulator it works well but when i install the app on device the swiping between pages is very laggy.

I notice that a lot of time is taking buy:

- `masksToBounds` - i need to have some circle view-s
- `addSubview` - there are a lot of them

and draw all views in `drawRect` involve to change all the methods and order and also there will be different behaviour on resize.

The Question is how can i fix the lag ? is `drawRect` better then subviews ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i came up is to have a container where i place all the views then i convert that view to the `UIImage` and from 20 `UIView`'s i manage to reduce to one `UIImageView`

I use this method for getting the image from UIView:

```
- (UIImage *)snapShotForView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you an alternative. I've recently developed a calendar based iOS application and had used this already available [FSCalendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fscalendar) tool. This works pretty smooth on simulator & device while scrolling across month views.

So, you might want to try this out!

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote here. My intention was to let OP know that there are already smooth running calendars available. So, if it suits OP, instead of re-inventing the wheel, it could be re-used. Thats the whole purpose of SO & Git-Hub communities/tools. Disappointing!